# Can I detect my iPhone when thief logout from iCloud in Settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, settings

I don't have iPhone but I want to know just for knowledge purpose, Can I detect my iPhone when thief logout from iCloud in Settings ?

I know we can detect our iPhone when we login on iCloud website with same apple id as device login but what if device logout from that apple id. can we still detect our iPhone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot logout iCloud without entering the password if **Find My iPhone** is enabled. At least, this counts for iOS7.

With versions prior iOS 7 you can wipe the device without having the password.